# hidden nodes don't show up with childnodewithname

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, location, hidden, touches

I'm building a list with a checkbox function, where the check symbol is a child of the empty check box.  In touchesBegan:, the checkbox should go from hidden to unhidden, and back, with each touch of the checkbox.  The code looks like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        for node in self.nodesAtPoint(location) {
            if node.childNodeWithName("checkSymbol")?.hidden == true {
                node.childNodeWithName("checkSymbol")?.hidden = false
            } else if childNodeWithName("checkSymbol")?.hidden == false {
                node.childNodeWithName("checkSymbol")?.hidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the childNode (the checkSymbol node) is not being picked up by the `.nodesAtPoint()` method when it's hidden.  That's the reason I've tried to workaround using the `.childNodeWithName()` approach above, but the box remains checked for subsequent touches.  Has anyone a suggestion for how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish for hidden nodes to be picked up by the `nodesAtPoint` you can always change your implementation of *hidden*.

You could alternatively use `node.zPosition = -1`, presuming you have a background node with *zPosition 0* to hide behind.